# Copy list of files with the Windows "Skip All" / "Replace All" file dialog

Tags: vb.net

I have a List with about 200 filepaths to be copied to a new location (replacing the root of the path from a remote, to a local).  (from about 6 different directories)

I'd like the user to be prompted with the standard File Copy dialog box when conflicts occur.  Specifically where it gives the option to "Skip all files" or "Replace all files"

I can use the FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile and choose the "FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs".  This gets the dialog box I'm expecting, but because you can only pass a single sourceFilename and destinationFilename, if many/all of the files already exist, the user is then prompted with the dialog for each file.

```
Dim filesToBeCopied as List(Of String)

For Each remoteFile in filesToBeCopied
   FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile(remoteFile, GetLocalPath(remoteFile), FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException)
Next
```

Again, the above produces the 'right' dialog box, but for every iteration.  I'm looking for it to prompt the user on conflict either
1) once.  period. or,
2) once per directory.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you will have to do your own 'dialog'.

Comment: [FileSystem.CopyDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copydirectory). You'll get the standard dialog with the *Do this for the next (N) conflicts* checkbox.

Comment: @Jimi  The CopyDirectory is mostly what I want.  Unfortunately, I'm pulling select files from some directories instead of just copying the entire contents.  But maybe I can leverage it when rolling my own per dbasnett's suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, `CopyFile` only deals with a single file. If you want to implement and customize a system-like functionality for multiple files yourself, see the [IFileOperation interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) which replaces the older [SHFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationw) function.